# Materialize CSS Remove table head spacing

Tags: materialize

I making a simple demo where i have few employees information. I am using materialize css table. But i am getting extra space between sr.no and other column names.

[image: My table image with doubt]

here is my code :

```
     <br/>

     <div class="row">
  <div class="col l8">
        <div class="card darken-2">
              <div class="card-content">
                    <span class="card-title">{{tableTitle}}</span>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="input-field col s4">
                                <input id="empSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search">

                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                          <div class="col lg7">
                                <table class="bordered highlight responsive-table">
                                      <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                  <th>Sr.no</th>
                                                  <th>Name</th>
                                                  <th>Age</th>
                                                  <th>Gender</th>
                                                  <th>Address</th>
                                                  <th>Designation</th>
                                                  <th>Department</th>
                                                  <th>Salary</th>
                                                  <th></th>
                                                  <th></th>

                                            </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                            <tr *ngFor="let item of EmployeeData;let i= index">
                                                  <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{item.Age}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{item.Gender}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{item.Address}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{item.Designation}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{item.Department}}</td>
                                                  <td>{{item.Salary}}</td>
                                                  <td>
                                                       <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                                                  </td> 
                                                   <td>
                                                       <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                                                  </td>                                                    
                                            </tr>
                                      </tbody>

                                </table>
                          </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not sure whether Materialize offers something specific for this, but typically you'd just set the CSS `width` of your column headers (or define the actual colums in HTML).

Answer (score 0):

in the `<th>` you could set `width="30px"` or whatever your're comfortable with. 
The icons, I'd put in one cell, and use `text-align: right`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="30px">Sr.no</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Designation</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th></th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{i+1}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Age}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Gender}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Address}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Designation}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Department}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Salary}}</td>
      <td style="text-align: right">
        <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```